# How do I get the time in the change log to be the same as my local time?

Tags: joomla, logs, sysadmin, timezone

I am working with CiviCRM in a Joomla environment. The Joomla server time is set for UTC and can verify changes to articles are logged at the correct time. However changes made to CiviCRM consituent records are shown as 6 hours behind. How do I get the CiviCRM change log time to be UTC?

Answer (score 1):

Check your timezone setting in Joomla.

Go to System, Global Configuration

Click on the Server tab and go to Location Settings

Comment: Thank you. We have already done this but CiviCRM does not pick up the time that Joomla is using. Any other ideas please.